# How to check if Elasticsearch is running using CURL?

Tags: ubuntu, elasticsearch, curl, kibana

I have downloaded the latest `ElasticSearch` & Kibana to my local machine (Ubuntu 20).

After extraction, I execute `bin/elasticsearch` & `bin/kibana`.

Execution successfully, I can open kibana running fine in my browser `http://localhost:5601/`

But from the CLI, using CURL command couldnot reach  curl -XGET http://localhost:9200/`

In the [document](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elastic-stack-get-started/8.0/get-started-elastic-stack.html#_make_sure_that_elasticsearch_is_up_and_running) I have followed
there is written a command to check if elasticsearch is up and running.

```
curl --cacert $ES_PATH_CONF/tls_auto_config_<timestamp>/http_ca.crt -u elastic https://localhost:9200
```

But I do not understand what is `$ES_PATH_CONF/tls_auto_config_<timestamp>`.

Can anybody please help me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am assuming you have followed the below steps to install on `Linux` as per documentation.

```
curl -L -O https://artifacts.elastic.co/downloads/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-8.0.1-linux-x86_64.tar.gz
tar -xzvf elasticsearch-8.0.1-linux-x86_64.tar.gz
cd elasticsearch-8.0.1
./bin/elasticsearch
```

According to this step you must be in `elasticsearch-8.0.1`.

`/elasticsearch-8.0.1` - **ES_HOME** folder.
`/elasticsearch-8.0.1/config` - **ES_PATH_CONF** folder.
`/elasticsearch-8.0.1/config/certs/http_ca.crt` - **HTTP CA** Certificate.

When you start Elasticsearch for the first time, passwords are generated for the `elastic` user and TLS is automatically configured for you.

Open same path in another terminal window or tab.

So you need to pass the `http_ca.crt` path to the `curl` command like below.

```
curl --cacert config/certs/http_ca.crt -u "elastic:password" https://localhost:9200
```

Also You can set the environment variable.

```
export ES_HOME=/path-to-ES_HOME/elasticsearch-8.0.1
export ES_PATH_CONF=/path-to-ES_HOME/elasticsearch-8.0.1/config
```

You can use environment variable directly in curl

```
curl --cacert $ES_PATH_CONF/certs/http_ca.crt -u "elastic:password" https://localhost:9200
```

The `password` must have shown while installing the elasticsearch. If you have not noted, you can change with below command:

```
bin/elasticsearch-reset-password -u elastic
```

You can refer more here https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/targz.html#_check_that_elasticsearch_is_running

Comment: Thanks. When I run `curl --cacert config/certs/http_ca.crt -u "elastic:password" https://localhost:9200`, it worked. SO every time I need to run this line to use curl ?

Comment: Yes, It added for security purpose.

Answer (score 2):

My guess is that you have not installed any cert than you can simply use below command.

```
curl -u elastic https://localhost:9200
```

Comment: Thanks. When I execute it gives me SSL error. I tried to add  cacert.pem file 
 from `https://curl.haxx.se/ca/cacert.pem` to my php.ini file. But still it show error `curl (60) ssl certificate problem self signed certificate in certificate chain`

Comment: Enter host password for user 'elastic':
curl: (60) SSL certificate problem: self signed certificate in certificate chain
More details here: https://curl.haxx.se/docs/sslcerts.html

`curl failed to verify the legitimacy of the server and therefore could not
establish a secure connection to it. To learn more about this situation and
how to fix it, please visit the web page mentioned above.` This was the error I encountered.

Comment: Adding `-k` worked `curl -u elastic https://localhost:9200 -k` Thanks. @Amit